# Insert in Cursor loop and Exception handling - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a table called DUD which is pretty much Static (which means once the data is inserted it never changes). I query data from DUD and populate a staging table CAR from which Webmethods polls everyday.

Usually it is 10 records for **every transaction**. There are two transactions per day.

I have written a Cursor to do this and I am happy with the logic.

The output will look like:

```
TRANSID   A    B    C   cnt
------   ---  ---   --  ---
A123     JIM  NY   ACT   1
A123     BOB  CA   ACT   2
A123     PIN  GA   ACT   3
--------------------------
A124     MIK  CA   ACT   1
A124     JON  MA   ACT   2
A124     CON  MY   ACT   3
A124     JIB  CA   ACT   4
```

What really concerns me and question is:

1. If the insert in the loop fails, it should rollback all the inserts made in this transaction and do not end up with partially inserted records or orphaned records for **a transaction**. I commit only after the loop is completed no exception was raised.
2. When exception happens, I also want to know which record failed to insert. I hope to catch this in my exception and call a function in the exception handler that will insert this information in to an Error table for further investigation.
3. The auto commit is disabled in the DB. But will oracle consider ALL the insert through a loop as one transaction or independent transactions and insert it immediately?

**Code**

```
  DECLARE  TYPE message_info 
  IS 
    RECORD 
    ( 
      message_code INTEGER, 
      message      VARCHAR2(500)); 
    msg MESSAGE_INFO; 
    tranid  NUMBER; 
    p_error EXCEPTION; 
    CURSOR b1 IS 
      SELECT * 
      FROM   dud 
      WHERE  dud.DATE = SYSDATE 
      AND    dud.status='ACTIVE'; 

  BEGIN 
    IF *CHECK SOME condition* 
      BEGIN 
        tranid = seq_transid.NEXTVAL; 
        --- Transaction id is unique per transaction. 
        --- All 10 records will have same transaction id. 
        FOR b1 IN c1 
        LOOP 
          i=b1%rowcount; 
          INSERT INTO car 
                      ( 
                                  transid, 
                                  a, 
                                  b, 
                                  c, 
                                  cnt 
                      ) 
                      VALUES 
                      ( 
                                  tranid, 
                                  b1.a, 
                                  b1.b, 
                                  b1.c, 
                                  i 
                      ); 

        END LOOP; 
      EXCEPTION 
      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        ROLLBACK; 
        msg.message := 'Unable to insert into CAR Table'; 
        RAISE p_error; 
      END; 
      COMMIT; 
    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN p_error THEN 
      error.post_msg (msg.message, SQLCODE,SQLERRM,USER); 
    END IF; 
  END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FORALL statement also in this situation....

you are using cursor and in loop you are inserting into tables..
you can directly insert all the transactions in one shot. this will increase the performance of your code as well and this will give you surety also that all transaction inserted or none of them have inserted...

Comment: Even better, he can insert-select, ie: INSERT INTO CAR(TransID,A,B,C,cnt) (select tranid, A,B,C, rownum from DUD WHERE DUD.DATE = SYSDATE AND DUD.STATUS='ACTIVE')

Comment: I agree with both Cade and Pratik. I want to use a for loop and cursor because, I want to also insert a sequence/order of the records inserted in that transaction by using the variable i in my code which gets the rowcount.

Please see my added output in my post above:

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in the situation you describe, there shouldn't be a problem, since you commit only after rollback.
But maybe it would be better to use [AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/AutonomousTransactions.php) for the function that logs the error. In general, one should avoid using it, but since you need to do some atomic transaction (for logging the record) it might be better, so you'll be sure that this commit will not commit the inserts made in the loop.

Comment: I agree with both Cade and Pratik. I want to use a for loop and cursor because, I want to also insert a sequence/order of the records inserted in that transaction by using the variable i in my code which gets the rowcount.

Please see my added output in my post above: